# Case of double dot in url regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url

```
(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//="]*)
```

[regex101.com/r/vd3hHQ/1](https://regex101.com/r/vd3hHQ/1/)

I am using above regex for detecting urls in input text. It passes the case of `wealth.in..mutual`, but instead it should just take `wealth.in`.
I need to put max consecutive occurrence count for dot in the last part of regex.

Previously, I was using

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>$@,]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one . It will check the valid urls.

```
(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, but this isn't passing most of the other cases :(

Comment: Please explain your long regex, it will greatly improve the quality of your response and help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal refactoring which excludes dot from the humongous character range and rearranges things around that.
(Wrapped over multiple lines so I can comment on what changed.)

```
# Beginning is the same as before
(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?
# Here, we exclude dot, and then allow it separately,
# and repeat one or more times.
# Also, DNS labels can be at most 63 characters
(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+~#=]{1,63}\.)+
# Same as before
[a-z]{2,6}\b
# A similar refactoring occurred here
((?:[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+~#?&//="]+\.)*
# Same as before
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+~#?&//="]+)?
```

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/zRTeTI/2

I haven't reviewed this for correctness otherwise; typically, URL regexes you find on the internet are flawed one way or another, so proceed with caution.  For example, this would at least still seem to fail on IDNA TLDs.

Comment: Also not sure why the slash is doubled inside the character classes; maybe this is a weird requirement of JavaScript? Or just an error.